# Get data-attribute and put it somewhere else? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

So I'm getting the data-id attribute like this:

```
$(this).data("id")
```

And now I need to put the result of the data-id somewhere else in my jQuery code.

So I need the result to be printed here:

```
selector: 'DATA-ID-RESULT',
```

Can anyone shed any light - I'm not sure what to do

Comment: What's wrong with using a variable? Not sure what is your question

Comment: will you please elaborate "somewhere else in my jQuery code" ?

Comment: `selector: $(this).data("id")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this

```
var selectorVlaue=$(this).data("id")+"-RESULT";
selector: selectorVlaue',
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is your question. In an assumption are you looking to use that value in your code? if so,

```
    var data_id = $(this).data("id");
    ......
    selector:data_id,
    ......
```

Is this what you are expecting?